# Does New York State law require me to e-file if I use TurboTax?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, state-income-tax, new-york, turbotax

If I use Turbo Tax to prepare my taxes with locally installed software, and specifically Turbo Tax with New York State, to prepare my returns, am I permitted to file my returns by mail and paper, or does state law require e-filing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When you e-file your taxes with TurboTax, does Intuit get a copy of your personal information?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/93784/when-you-e-file-your-taxes-with-turbotax-does-intuit-get-a-copy-of-your-persona)

Comment: "does state law require efile through Intuit" That would be astonishing. I don't believe Intuit has that much lobby.

Comment: @void_ptr Good catch. I'll try to edit a bit.

Comment: With the recent edit, this is question is no longer a duplicate, and I have retracted my close vote.

Comment: @BenMiller - do you want to remove the duplicate reference as well?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I would leave it, as it is a related question that answers the half of the OP’s question that he subsequently deleted.

Comment: Interesting test case. Depending on how members treat the review queue, all it will take is three to see a trusted member mark this as duplicate, and they may vote to close it as a duplicate for that reason without doing their diligence. The experiment has begun

Answer (score 3):

From New York State: [E-file requirement for individual taxpayers](https://www.tax.ny.gov/pit/efile/efile_mandate_for_individuals.htm)

> Who must e-file
>
> You're **required to electronically file** your return if you meet all
>   three of the following conditions:
>
> - you use software to prepare your own personal income tax return; **and**
> - your software supports the electronic filing of your return; **and**
> - you have broadband Internet access.

So if using TurboTax to prepare software, than you must at least efile through the tax software. And from answer links above, efiling will require certain information being stored by Intuit.

Comment: Wow, what a terrible, completely unenforceable law. There is really no way for the state to know if you meet those conditions or not.

Comment: @BenMiller NYS has lots of those. Often times there is no punishment either. It helps reduce load thats all. You can be a rebel without a cause and print off all the forms your tax software fills in behind the scenes, and fax them over.

Comment: But it means that there is absolutely no way you can confirm that the information sent to the State is accurate and yet you are required to certify that it is accurate!

Comment: By "certain information" I think you mean "*all* the information you send"...